Why is "const { userId } = await auth()" returning null using Clerk on a Next.js app?
I'm encountering an issue where userId returned by Clerk's auth() helper is null, even though I'm wrapping my application with the ClerkProvider. Below are the details of my setup and code:
Docs: https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/auth#use-auth-to-retrieve-user-id
export async function CreateProduct(unsafeData: z.infer<typeof productDetailsSchema>) {
    //this returns null
    const { userId }: { userId: string | null } = await auth()
    const { success, data } =  productDetailsSchema.safeParse(unsafeData)

    if (userId === null) {
        return { 
            error: true, 
            message: 'There was an error creating your product. userId is null' 
        }
    } else if (!success) {
        return { 
            error: true, 
            message: 'There was an error creating your product. Request was unsuccesful' 
        }
    }

    const { id } = await createProductDb({ ...data, clerkUserId: userId })

    redirect(`/dashboard/products/${id}/edit?tab=countries`)
}

This is my middleware setup:
import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

const isPublicRoute = createRouteMatcher([
  '/', 
  '/sign-in(.*)',
  '/sign-up(.*)',
  '/api(.*)'
]) 

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, req) => {
  if (!isPublicRoute(req)) {
    auth.protect();
  }
})

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip Next.js internals and all static files, unless found in search params
    '/((?!_next|[^?]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)',
    // Always run for API routes
    '/(api|trpc)(.*)',
  ],
};


Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Expected Behavior:
The auth() helper should return the authenticated user's userId.
Actual Behavior:
userId is always null.
Clerk and Next Versions:
@clerk/backend@1.20.3
@clerk/nextjs@6.8.0
next@15.0.4
